# What does or None mean?

Tags: python

In a project I'm working on I found this code:

```
official = bill.official and employees.loadById(bill.official) or None
```

What's the point of the `or None`? In my opinion it doesn't change anything.

Comment: It has to do with the semantics of `or`. If `A` is not truthy in `A or B` then `B` is returned

Comment: It means that in case that either `bills.official` or `employees.loadById(bill.official)` have a *"falsey"* value (like an empty list or string), `None` will be returned **instead** of this falsey value

Comment: It is possible that `or None` could be to make the code more self-documenting. Perhaps `bill.official` and `employees.loadById(bill.official)` already take on `None` for their falsey values, in which case the explicit `or None` is redundant, but its presence emphasizes to whoever reads the code that `None` is a possible outcome of the assignment.

Comment: It might also be used for consistency with other parts of the code. For example, `official` is checked for being falsey as `None`. This way if `bill.official` might return an empty list, you "convert" it to `None` which is the program's falsey value

Comment: Python 2.5 added a conditional expression to avoid this kind of use of `and` and `or`: `official = employees.loadById(bill.official) if bill.official else None`. This code is either very old, or written by someone with old habits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will return the value of `employees.loadById(bill.official)` if both `bill.official` and `employees.loadById(bill.official)` are True or are not None, but will Return None if 1 or more of those is None or False. hope that makes sense.

example:

```
a = 1
b = 2
a and b or None
Out[26]: 2
b and a or None
Out[27]: 1
a = None
b and a or None
a and b or None
```

Comment: The logical operators are not limited to Boolean operands.

Comment: I was pointing out the difference between "are True " and "are truthy".

Answer (score 1):

`official = bill.official and employees.loadById(bill.official) or None`

---

For the above statement, if `bill.official` and `employees.loadById(bill.official)` both the values are true, then the official variable value will be `True`.

if `bill.official` or `employees.loadById(bill.official)` value is `False`, then the official variable value will be `None`.

Comment: You are correct but not accurate as to the distinction between `True` or `False` and *truthy* or *falsey*. Meaning, `bill.official` and `employees.loadById(bill.official)` **does NOT** have to be booleans nor the result of `and`ing then **does NOT** have to return a boolean

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the truth value of the variables.

Without `or None`, if either of `bill.official` or `employees.loadById(bill.official)` has truth value of `False`, then `official` variable will have value of the first Falsy variable among them.

With `or None`, the effect is that:

=> If both `bill.official` and `employees.loadById(bill.official)` are truthy values, `employees.loadById(bill.official)` is assigned to `official`

=> Otherwise `None` is assigned to `official`.

See [Truth Value Testing - Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) to find out which values have thruth values.